# Alteryx Analyse the similarity of the words

Tags: alteryx

I am currently doing out the top 10 types of fault chart. So the user will key in what is the fault about, ex. light bulb fused. As it is free flow text box, the words may not be the same. Is there anyway to make Alteryx understand that some words may be the same, allowing me to find the top 10 types of fault. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of ways. You can use the Fuzzy Match tools in the Join category to sort out slight spelling mistakes. You can find Alteryx examples of Fuzzy Match on Youtube.

You can also use the Record ID followed by Text to Columns (Split to Rows based on space) to get a list of single words.

In what you are trying to do, I would advise building up a bit of a lookup table. You can then use the Find-Replace Tool to Append the Category from the lookup depending on the words that are found.

Depending on the cleanliness of your data and how different each category is will guide you as to how far down the above paths you should go.